# AWS S3 Write At Offset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is there any possibility to write at some offset inside S3 stored file? We really really don't want to download it for read-modify-write all the time because files are rather big (few GBs each).

Comment: This is not possible to do in S3.

Comment: What if you use [multipart object _copies_](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingRESTMPUapi.html) to make a copy of your S3 object, but only up to the parts where you want to start appending (by continuing the multipart upload)?

Comment: Need to change the content of the file frequently, so... not possible ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to *append* data in S3.

One possible workaround could be to create new files every time (possibly using [Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/)) and run EMR jobs (possibly using [Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/)) to merge these small files at hourly or daily cadence as needed.

Comment: We don't need to append, we need to overwrite. We might look at changing file format entirely, thanks for pointing out!